# Have to write a program that gives me the sum of even numbers without using if statements nor loops nor array how should I do that in java?

Tags: java

I want to write a program that makes the user enter 3 integers num1,num2,num3 and give me the sum of the even numbers entered and the average of the even numbers without using if statements/loop/arrays I'm stuck can't figure it out.

Comment: Using streams ? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html

Comment: Ternary operator.

Comment: Please [make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/6619250)

Answer (score 3):

Without using any conditional statements, `if`, `else`, ternary, or any library function.

The following operation will convert `num1` to zero if it's odd.  But will leave the value as-is, if it's even.

```
num1 = num1 - num1*(num1 % 2);
```

You see what it does?  It exploits the modulo operator, `num1 % 2`, to convert the number into a zero or one.

Apply this same operation to num2 and num3:

```
num2 = num2 - num2*(num2 % 2);
num3 = num3 - num3*(num3 % 2);
```

Then add the adjusted values:

```
sumOfEvens = num1 + num2 + num3;
```

**Update:**

The above formula doesn't handle negative numbers since `(-1) % 2` is -1 instead of   `1` But here's a hint on how to fix this:

```
int isNegative = (num1 >> 31) & 0x01;
```

`isNegative` will be zero when `num1` is positive.  And it will be 1 when it is is negative.

The rest is left to you as an exercise.

Comment: don't forget to upvote and/or accept if you found the answer helpful

Comment: @ErikMacias - I also updated my answer to address negative numbers.

Comment: very nice answer, I just wonder how about the even number, is it possible to convert even number to zero?

Comment: @TanSang - yes, of course.   I'll give you a hint: try applying the `!` operator in one or places in the above expression tests.

Comment: I am not familiar with bit operator, Maybe, this one is easier to understand `num1 = (num1 % 2) * (num1 % 2) * num1`

Answer (score 2):

You could use streams and `filter()` like

```
int num1 = 2, num2 = 3, num3 = 4;
int sum = IntStream.of(num1, num2, num3).filter(x -> x % 2 == 0).sum();
double count = IntStream.of(num1, num2, num3).filter(x -> x % 2 == 0).count();
System.out.printf("sum of evens is %d and the average is %.2f%n", sum, sum / count);
```

or a chain of ternary operations like

```
int sum = (num1 % 2 == 0 ? num1 : 0) 
        + (num2 % 2 == 0 ? num2 : 0) + (num3 % 2 == 0 ? num3 : 0);
double count = (num1 % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 0) 
        + (num2 % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 0) + (num3 % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

IntStream.of(num1, num2, num3).filter(num -> num % 2 == 0).sum()